# What's the point of Actions and Reducers in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been using Redux for a while, but I still can't see the point of actions and reducers.

As described in the [docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions), a reducer can be summarised as `(previousState, action) => newState`. The same principle applies for React's [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

So this reducer function basically handles all actions, which seems like a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle. I'm sure that there's a good reason to do it this way, but I don't see it.

It would make more sense to me to just have a function per action. So instead of having an `ADD_TODO` action you would have a `addTodo(previousState, todoText) => newState` function. This would reduce (no pun intended) a lot of boilerplate code and might even give a slight performance improvement as you no longer need to `switch` through the action types.

**So my question is:** What's the advantage of having a reducer as opposed to a single-action function?

Comment: How does having multiple functions is more performant than one function?

Comment: @Ramesh The difference is probably neglectable, but you would no longer need to `switch` through all the action types when you call a function directly.

Comment: "So this reducer function basically handles all actions" you can have multiple reducers that modify different states. One reducer for one action would result in too many functions. So using a new reducer when you want to maintain and update a completely new state of an app is a bit better.

Comment: If you think that your reducer has too many switch statements then maybe redux-saga can help you. Although this would again do something like the switch statements.

Comment: @Ramesh I personally don't see the problem in having "too many functions" if it increases maintainability regarding single responsibility. Another advantage of functions is that it allows tree shaking.

Comment: @DuncanLuk - all reducers receiving all actions is a feature not a bug. It allows you to separate your state and respond, in separate reducers, in different ways to the same action (if necessary). There's a million ways to structure reducers, create higher order reducers, etc. If you've got "one" reducer and you're doing a ton of things in it, you probably are violating the single responsibility principle, but redux isn't encouraging you to do it, you're just doing it on your own. https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/structuring-reducers#reducer-concepts-and-techniques

Comment: @DuncanLuk In some react projects when the reducers get large because of the multiple switch statements the developers generally move the logic which updates the state to new functions(that are defined outside the reducer function) and call them within the switch statement. This will make your reducer function a bit leaner.

Comment: I understand that there are ways to split up reducers, but that's not really what I'm asking. I would just like to know what the advantage of using a reducer is in the first place.

Comment: Single responsibility principle. A reducer manages state (if the reducer gets to big, very simply split it up, it's not hard). An action is NOT supposed to define how the state is manipulated, an action is simply an "event" - a reducer defines how the state is manipulated (if at all) in response to an event occurring. The same event could have an effect on multiple parts of your state that are otherwise unrelated. It would be a violation of single responsibility principle for that event to know how to manipulate your state - the event doesn't know ANYTHING about your state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if your question is why do we use `reducers` at all?

> The real boilerplate of Flux is conceptual: the need to emit an
>   update, the need to register the Store with a Dispatcher, the need for
>   the Store to be an object (and the complications that arise when you
>   want a universal app).

That is a fundamental design choice `redux` has made as it is inspired from `flux`.

If you do not like the `switch` cases, and there by the reducer size. You can have something like this below:

```
export const todos = createReducer([], {
  [ActionTypes.ADD_TODO]: (state, action) => {
    const text = action.text.trim()
    return [...state, text]
  }
})
```

Above is a function that lets us express reducers as an object mapping from action types to handlers.

`createReducer` can be defined as :

```
function createReducer(initialState, handlers) {
  return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
      return handlers[action.type](state, action)
    } else {
      return state
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more on this [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/reducing-boilerplate)

Comment: That's a nice way to declare reducers. This actually solves the single-responsibility and performance issues that I mentioned, thanks! I just wanted to add that you might want to support multiple handlers per action for scalability.

Comment: @DuncanLuk It is generally considered a good practice to do only one task (handler?) per action. 

You can do mutliple tasks within an action, by dispatching more actions inside another action.
But that is largely subjective and depends how you want structure your code.
Here is another good resource on this: https://redux.js.org/faq/reducers/

Comment: There might be a situation where you'd update two independent parts of your state based on the same action (event). In that case you probably don't want to do that in the same handler. But you're right, that completely depends on how you want to structure your code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is a silly design and makes no sense.

It is just a kind of over-engineering. Because in most case, you could have just used a simpler function to update a state instead of doing it a silly way by making it two functions (reducer and action).

By adopting redux in your project, you may write tons of reducer and action codes which looks extremely ugly and difficult to do code reviews

Try to imagine, if useState function is design by redux way!

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
```

this one line code now would looks like this(tons of ugly codes):

```
export interface TODO {
  name: string
}

export interface ITodosAction {
  type:
    | "SET_TODOS";
  payload: {
    todos?: TODO[];
  };
}
export default function todosReducer(
  state: TODO[] = [],
  action: ITodosAction
): TODO[] {

export function setTodos(todos: TODO[]): ITodosAction {
  return {
    type: "SET_TODOS",
    payload: { todos }
  };
}

const todos = useSelector(state=>state.todos)
dispatch(setTodos(["A", "B"]));
```

if useState became like this, we would have to suffer using react (thanks to react's team for not adopting an over-engineering and silly design like redux).

Remember: never try to figure out why this design is good when it has already brought you trouble. We use redux not because redux is good (instead it is a worst design i've ever seen) but because we don't have many choices

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not appreciating how flexible reducers are, you can create as many of them as you like:

```
const initialState = {
    key: 'someValue',
    key2: 'someValue',
    key3: {
        key31: 'someValue',
        key32: 'someValue',
        key33: []
    }
}

// all the below reducers can live in separate files and only handle a single action, if they want, no switches involved at all
const key = (state = initialState.key, action) => { /* the logic to be performed at 'key' */ }
const key2 = (state = initialState.key, action) => { /* the logic to be performed at 'key2' */ }

const key31 = (state = initialState.key3.key31, action) => { /* the logic to be performed at 'key3.key31' */ }
const key32 = (state = initialState.key3.key32, action) => { /* the logic to be performed at 'key3.key32' */ }
const key33 = (state = initialState.key3.key33, action) => { /* the logic to be performed at 'key3.key33' */ }
const key3 = combineReducers({key31,key32,key33})

// this is the top level reducer for your store
const myTopLevelReducer = combineReducers({key,key2,key3});
```

Comment: You would still need to check for the action type per sub-reducer, right? This doesn't really explain the advantage of a reducer as opposed to a single-action function.

Comment: Actions SHOULD NOT know anything about your state. Reducers SHOULD NOT know about all and every action (this is why there's a `default: return state`) only the actions that **are relevant to it**. It's very easy to maintain if done correctly and extremely easy to test. Single action functions require your action to know about your state - violation of single responsibility - actions do not care about that shape or your state and you should be able to refactor the shape of your state without changing anything about your actions (see the purpose of `selectors` in redux)

Comment: @DuncanLuk - of course your would need to the for the action type per sub reducer - if the action isn't relevant to that piece of state, then you just return the `state` argument. But it's a whitelist check, not a blacklist, hence it's much smaller.

Comment: Rather than talk about single responsibility, it's probably better to talk about [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. So if I understand correctly, you can consider an action to be an event and a reducer an event-listener. I definitely see the advantage in that in terms of separation of concerns. However, it seems like a reducer usually listens to multiple events (to stay in this terminology), which still brings up my SRP concern.

Comment: A reducer does listen to multple events, by default it listens to every event. But that doesn't mean it has to respond to every event (and indeed it shouldn't). It only needs to respond to the events that it is concerned with (which is why there is a `default: return state`).

It actually increases boilerplate if you have to define the events a reducer is concerned with because you have to 1. define these events somewhere and tell redux only to send these events to you and 2. listen to these events in the reducer. It's by far easier just to do the second thing.

Comment: If you suffer from performance issues, you can easily create higher order reducers to "filter out" events, but this is necessary only in extremely rare cases. Your reducer function(s) are synchronous and should be extremely simple, so you'll likely never need this "filtering" functionality.

Comment: In solution 2 that you mention you'd still have to define which events you want to listen to in every reducer. As a solution I can imagine an API where you would just do something like `redux.onAction(myActionType, myHandler)`, where `myHandler` would be a single-action reducer. That way nothing would really change except enforced single-responsibility. But that discussion might be better suited as a feature request. If you would summarise your comments into your answer for future readers then I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: You have to define those events **regardless** in your reducer. Even if your reducer only ever handles one action. `myReducer = (state,action) => action.type === 'addOne' ? state + 1 : state`.

The alternative is telling redux you only ever want to receive actions where `action.type === 'addOne'` and then handling it. The current implementation is simpler than what you're proposing. Redux does have an `onAction` listener by default - it's called "calling the reducer". A redux store only has a single reducer, it could be one function or a thousand different ones that you combined into one.

Comment: Don't take this as an insult, but it seems like you're either relatively new to redux or have worked on projects where it's never been implemented cleanly. Trust it, it's extremely popular for a reason. Unfortunately, as hard as redux has tried, it's also very easy to abuse it (e.g. impure reducers are discouraged, but there's no way to enforce them) and use it incorrectly, in which case people start to think redux is stupid because they've never seen it or used it in a "good" way.

Comment: The thing is that with such an `onAction` API you would move that `action.type === 'addOne'` out of the reducer, which reduces the complexity inside the reducer, enforces SRP, and gives that small performance improvement that I mentioned. It wouldn't necessarily decrease the amount of code, but it would increase maintainability. That would be the advantage. But again, StackOverflow is probably not the best place for such a discussion.

Comment: The same number of logical statements occur, you've just moved them around so it hasn't changed complexity at the application level at all. Same as anything, learn the "rules" of redux really well, and once you've mastered them, then feel free to break them.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point. It's not about decreasing complexity in the application, it's about moving the complexity outside of the reducer, which gives the advantages I mentioned.